# How to map an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and practicing different API to fetch the data and play with it. Although I am dealing with this flickr API which is returning data like "An array inside an object"

```json
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 10,
    "perpage": 100,
    "total": "1000",
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "51351784082",
        "owner": "10706882@N07",
        "secret": "4b8734223e",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "Walnuts topping and bread",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "51351786287",
        "owner": "131221068@N03",
        "secret": "cb4e315e52",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "Amapola Flyg / Fokker 50 / SE-MFY / EIDW",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

I want to access the photo array to map through its properties like secret and id to generate image link to eventually show the image. But the data returning from the API is an object which has an array and i cannot access it. It is giving me error. Kindly check the code:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
  const [variable, setImgdata] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=09d770a1c3e5e480517dff043f458023&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157719623454163-39de62921689545c&api_sig=faf58b987d668d8b3cf264807a687c9b"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const variable = data.photos.photo.map((imgdata) => ({
          id: imgdata.photos.photo.id,
          secret: imgdata.photos.photo.secret,
          title: imgdata.photos.photo.title,
        }));
        setImgdata(variable);
      });
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing Here</h1>
      {variable.map((img) => (
        <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <img
            src={`https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/${img.id}_${img.secret}_w.jpg`}
            className="card-img-top"
            alt="..."
          />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{img.title}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

/*
const data = response.json();
const data_array = Object.keys(data);
console.log(data_array);
*/
```

It is giving me error like :

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined

It is not able to read photo array. Kindly help me what am i doing wrong here.
A fix to this code will be a great help

Comment: `data.photos.photo` is already the array you're talking about. Then why another `.photos.photo` in the `.map()`? `imgdata` is one of the "photo"s: `imgdata.id`, ...

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

When mapping over the array you are going over the individual items:
`photo` is no a property of the individual array element but of the main object.

Directly use :

```
        id: imgdata.id,
        secret: imgdata.secret,
        title: imgdata.title,
```

Comment: _"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo. While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.**"_ - How is this not a close-vote?

Comment: Certainly reproducible. And is not a typo. OP has an incorrect understanding of `.map()` and that is what I tried to clear. Closing this question means OP will not be able to reach a solution, and looks like they have genuinely tried to get to one.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have got the answer but here are few more issues with your code.

1. Pass the dependency array while using `useEffect` hook else it will cause unnecessary re rendering.
2. Add `key` prop when creating a list inside a map.
3. You can use destructuring to get the value of the keys from the `imgdata` data object

```js
function App() {
    const [variable, setImgdata] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(
            "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=09d770a1c3e5e480517dff043f458023&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157719623454163-39de62921689545c&api_sig=faf58b987d668d8b3cf264807a687c9b"
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {

                const variable = data.photos.photo.map((imgdata) => {                    // destructuring 
                    const {id, secret, title} = imgdata;
                    return {id, secret, title}
                });
                setImgdata(variable);
            });
    }, []); // dependency array

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Testing Here</h1>
            {variable.map((img) => (
                <div className="card" style={{width: "18rem"}} key={img.id}> // added key prop
                    <img
                        src={`https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/${img.id}_${img.secret}_w.jpg`}
                        className="card-img-top"
                        alt="..."
                    />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{img.title}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```